# Bogoliubov Hamiltonian in second order of perturbation

Tags: hamiltonian, bose-einstein-condensate, cold-atoms

I have a Hamitonian:
$$
H = \int d^3r \Big[\hat{\psi}^{\dagger} H_0 \hat{\psi} + \frac{g_0}{2} \hat{\psi}^{\dagger} \hat{\psi}^{\dagger} \hat{\psi}\hat{\psi} - \mu \hat{\psi}^{\dagger}\hat{\psi} \Big]
$$
and a peturbation to the bosonic field operator in the Bogoliubov approach:
$$
\hat{\psi} = \phi_0 \hat{a}_0 + \delta \hat{\psi}
$$
where $\hat{a}_0$ annihilates the condensate mode and by construction the perturbation is orthogonal to this mode:
$$
\delta \hat{\psi} = \hat{Q} \hat{\psi} = (1-\lvert\phi_0 \rangle \langle\phi_0\rvert) \hat{\psi}
$$
I want to prove that in the second order in $\delta \hat{\psi}$ the perturbation may be written as:

$$
H^{(2)} = f(N) + \frac{1}{2} \int d^3r
\begin{pmatrix}
\hat{\Lambda}^{\dagger} & -\hat{\Lambda}
\end{pmatrix}
\mathcal{L}
\begin{pmatrix}
\hat{\Lambda} \\
\hat{\Lambda}^{\dagger}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $f(N)$ is some constant dependent on the number of particles $N$, and
$$
\mathcal{L}=
\begin{pmatrix}
H_{GP} + g_0 N \hat{Q} |\phi_0|^2 \hat{Q} & g_0 N \hat{Q} \phi_0^2 \hat{Q}^* \\
-g_0 N \hat{Q}^* \phi_0^{*2} \hat{Q} & -H_{GP}^* - g_0 N \hat{Q}^* |\phi_0|^2 \hat{Q}^*
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
H_{GP} = H_0 + g_0(N-1)|\phi_0|^2 -\mu
$$
$$
\hat{\Lambda} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \hat{a}_0^{\dagger} \delta \hat{\psi}
$$
And there are following relations:
$$
\Big[ \hat{\Lambda}(r_1), \hat{\Lambda}^{\dagger}(r_2) \Big] = \delta(r_1 - r_2) - \phi_0(r_1) \phi^*_0(r_2)
$$
$$
\delta \hat{\psi} ^{\dagger} \delta \hat{\psi} \simeq \hat{\Lambda}^{\dagger}\hat{\Lambda}
$$
$$
\delta \hat{\psi}^{\dagger} \hat{a}_0^{\dagger} \hat{a}_0 \delta \hat{\psi} \simeq N \hat{\Lambda}^{\dagger}\hat{\Lambda}
$$
I tried to simply plugging $\hat{\psi} = \phi_0 \hat{a}_0 + \delta \hat{\psi}$ into $H$, but I'm stuck at some point.